# How to play music from the client to the server?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vnc, audio-streaming

I have a client computer that connects via VNC to the server (it does not have a display and is connected to a stereo). The problem is that I do not want to use server resources, for this reason playing the audio directly on the server is not a solution.

What I'm looking for is some software or VNC function that allows me to play music on the server from the client computer but without making the remote connection, that is, directly from the player.

**Is there any solution for this?**

My server computer has Windows XP and client Windows 7. If your solution requires an operating system different from Windows XP on the server, also raise the solution and specify the operating system required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you don't just use the windows 7(client) as music server and WinXP(server) as a client to stream it ? you only need to connect once via remote connect to start the player but then it's independently stream the music from music server(win7).

use VLC application.
here is the guide:  https://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/

Good luck

Comment: It could be a good alternative if I do not get what I want. Although the way you propose, I'm not sure I can choose the music I want to play on the client.

Comment: Yes you can as you are streaming it from the win7. Its like a radio station.  Whoever broadcast choose what to play and the streamer just listen and receive the audio.

Comment: Great! It's what I'm looking for. I would just like to avoid connecting remotely to start the player.
I searched and found PsExec (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) that allows me to run programs remotely.
Could using such applications be a security risk for the computer from which it is run?

Comment: No. This application is not a security risk.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for everything. Regards